# Android Studio Rendering Problems: android.support.design.widget.TabLayout class not found

Tags: android

When I add TabLayout inside my xml file it shows this error.
I also have these dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
}
```

[See Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkRgd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this dependency in gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Comment: I am using targetSdkVersion 24
and compileSdkVersion 24 & buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
So how can I add this ?

Comment: @SurojitJana  if so then use  "android.widget.TabLayout"  instead of "android.support.design.widget.TabLayout"

Comment: Same thing happens.
It says 
Rendering Problems 
The following classes could not be found:
- android.widget.TabLayout (Change to android.widget.TableLayout, Fix Build Path, Create Class)

Comment: what is your minimum sdk ?

Comment: minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 24

Comment: then you must have to  go with  "compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0' " and in android studio change preview version. No problem with target sdk & compile sdk go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build it or change preview Android version in here [Preview Android Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrHHm.png)

Comment: This is not a solution.